# Azure load balancer

Tags: azure, load-balancing

I am trying to configure my load balancer in Microsoft Azure, but got stuck as "CREATE A LOAD-BALANCED SET" option is disabled (grayed out).

I did the following steps:

1. I had created an ubuntu image.
2. I started 2 VMs using the ubuntu image under the same cloud service (xysite.cloudapp.net)
3. In the management portal, I clicked on VM1->Endpoint->"Add standalone endpoint".
4. According to Azure load balancer example, I should have "CREATE A LOAD-BALANCED SET" option enabled to create the set. For me, this option is disabled. :-(

Can someone please help me on configuring the Azure load balancer?

Thanks!

Comment: Which azure portal are you using?

Comment: Hi Dennis, I am using default portal (https://manage.windowsazure.com). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit old question, but just in case someone stumbles across:

If your VMs are running on a Basic Tier, then you cannot do load balancing. Here are the rough steps you need to follow:

- Delete the VM while retaining the attached disks.
- Go through the new VM wizard, go to custom and select your deleted VM's disk from "My Disks" on the left side.
- Make sure you select at least Standard Tier, go through the wizard & now you should be able to loadbalance your web server.